Already called DialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) , but dialog shows on the TOP and LEFT of screen
Just make a very simple dialog progress bar.(style is spinner)
Setting the attribute shoulb be at the center of screen.
DialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
On some devices,
The dialog shows at the center of screen, then it moves to top and left on the screen.
However, it works very well on other devices.(Always shows at the center of screen)
I have no idea why the same code but the UI is different on different device.

pls post complete code
